# Reading numpy array as all lowercase

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a dictionary where the values are lists of lists like so:

```
my_dict = {'project': [['Address', 'STREET', '123 N Main St'],
                       ['Address', 'STREET', '100 N Main St']]}
```

I'd like to check if a value exists in one of the lists and I have historically been using

```
for table in my_dict:
    if 'somevalue' in np.array(my_dict[table]):
        # do something
```

This has worked fine, but now that the lists have become large, duplicate values are popping up. I'd like to `.lower()` everything in the array as well as the string in order for reading sake. Something like this doesn't work the way I want it to:

```
for table in my_dict:
    if 'somevalue'.lower() in np.array(my_dict[table]).lower():
        # do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in creating an `np.array` here, it only slows things down. If your concern is flattening your lists of lists, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is one neat way of achieving that:

```
from itertools import chain
from timeit import timeit

a = [['Address', 'STREET', '123 N Main St'],
     ['Address', 'STREET', '100 N Main St']]

timeit(lambda: 'STREET' in np.array(a))
# 5.389413919008803
timeit(lambda: 'STREET' in chain.from_iterable(a))
# 0.29813046095659956
```

To lowercase everything use `map`

```
'street' in map(str.lower, chain.from_iterable(a))
# True
```

or a generator expression. This can be used to do the flattening, as well.

```
'street' in (y.lower() for x in a for y in x)
# True
```

A (flattening) list comprehension works in exactly the same way but would be slower here. (Rule of thumb: if you only use the list to go through it once and then discard it a generator expression is  more economical.)

```
'street' in [y.lower() for x in a for y in x]
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured a bit of a solution out (not sure if it's the fastest or best way but it does work). I created another array in place in order to read it, like so:

```
for table in my_dict:
    if 'somevalue'.lower() in np.array([[x.lower() for x in a] for a in my_dict[table]]):
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.char` has a bunch of functions that apply string methods to elements of an array.  They are designed more for convenience than speed:

```
In [116]: arr = np.array(my_dict['project'])                                    
In [117]: arr                                                                   
Out[117]: 
array([['Address', 'STREET', '123 N Main St'],
       ['Address', 'STREET', '100 N Main St']], dtype='<U13')
In [118]: np.char.lower(arr)                                                    
Out[118]: 
array([['address', 'street', '123 n main st'],
       ['address', 'street', '100 n main st']], dtype='<U13')
```

Or another function:

```
In [119]: np.char.capitalize(arr)                                               
Out[119]: 
array([['Address', 'Street', '123 n main st'],
       ['Address', 'Street', '100 n main st']], dtype='<U13')
```